# What are some usernames I should prohibit for my Mail Server?

Tags: email, email-filter, username

So, I'm starting to create an automated Registration script. It already checks for duplications, but that's not enough. I'd like to ask for some in the community, on which names users shouldn't be allowed to register.

I got these usernames already prohibited:

`"admin", "postmaster", "abuse", "daemon", "mailer-daemon", "support", "system", "root", "hostmaster", "postmaster", "host", "billing"`

Comment: I feel this question will attract a lot of fragmented answers that half answer the question. Unless there's a large source somewhere or one answer is edited to add more names to, I'm not sure how helpful the question is.

Comment: Having said that, 'info' and 'help' should be added.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Questions that ask for a list aren't really a good fit for the site.  The site is a knowledge base of questions with a specific factual answer.  Open-ended list requests tend to get partial answers and answers containing a mix of good and bad ideas, and a big collection of answers that are individually incomplete.  So it is difficult to identify the best answers or accept a best answer, which is integral to the site concept.  With a little more rep, you could ask a question like this in our Root Access chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [curated and maintained list](https://github.com/forwardemail/reserved-email-addresses-list) of ~200 admin, mailer-daemon, and no-reply usernames reserved for security concerns (that you should prevent from being used by non-admins) ([JSON format available](https://github.com/forwardemail/reserved-email-addresses-list/blob/master/admin-list.json):

- `abuse`
- `adm`
- `admin`
- `administracion`
- `administration`
- `administrator`
- `alert`
- `alerts`
- `app`
- `backup`
- `backups`
- `billing`
- `courier`
- `cron`
- `customer`
- `customer-care`
- `customer-service`
- `customer.care`
- `customer.service`
- `customercare`
- `customerservice`
- `daemon`
- `deploy`
- `dev`
- `developer`
- `developers`
- `dns`
- `dns-admin`
- `dns-operation`
- `dns.admin`
- `dns.operation`
- `dnsadmin`
- `dnsoperation`
- `do-not-reply`
- `do-not-respond`
- `do.not.reply`
- `donotreply`
- `donotrespond`
- `dont-reply`
- `dovecot`
- `email`
- `exim`
- `family-safety`
- `family.safety`
- `familysafety`
- `ftp`
- `ftps`
- `group`
- `groups`
- `hello`
- `help`
- `help-desk`
- `help.desk`
- `helpdesk`
- `host`
- `host-master`
- `host-name`
- `host.master`
- `host.name`
- `hostmaster`
- `hostname`
- `iana`
- `iana-admin`
- `iana-tech`
- `iana.admin`
- `iana.tech`
- `ianaadmin`
- `ianatech`
- `inbox`
- `info`
- `inquiries`
- `inquiry`
- `inquirys`
- `list`
- `list-request`
- `list.request`
- `local`
- `local-domain`
- `local-host`
- `local.domain`
- `local.host`
- `localdomain`
- `localhost`
- `logwatch`
- `lpt`
- `mail`
- `mail-daemon`
- `mail.daemon`
- `mailbox`
- `maildaemon`
- `mailer-daemon`
- `mailer.daemon`
- `mailerdaemon`
- `maintenance`
- `marketing`
- `media`
- `media-relations`
- `media.relations`
- `mediarelations`
- `mod`
- `moderator`
- `moderators`
- `monit`
- `news`
- `news-letter`
- `news.letter`
- `newsletter`
- `no-replies`
- `no-reply`
- `no-replys`
- `no.replies`
- `no.reply`
- `no.replys`
- `no_reply`
- `nobody`
- `noc`
- `noreplies`
- `noreply`
- `noreplys`
- `noticias`
- `notification`
- `notifications`
- `notify`
- `operations`
- `operator`
- `owner`
- `owners`
- `pay`
- `payment`
- `payments`
- `post-master`
- `post.master`
- `postbox`
- `postfix`
- `postmaster`
- `press`
- `printer`
- `privacy`
- `public`
- `refund`
- `refunds`
- `register`
- `registrar`
- `registration`
- `root`
- `sales`
- `security`
- `sendmail`
- `smtp`
- `ssl`
- `support`
- `sys`
- `sys-admin`
- `sys.admin`
- `sys.administrator`
- `sysadmin`
- `sysadministrator`
- `syslog`
- `system`
- `system-administrator`
- `system.administrator`
- `systems`
- `terms`
- `test`
- `tld`
- `tld-admin`
- `tld-ops`
- `tld-tech`
- `tld.admin`
- `tld.ops`
- `tld.tech`
- `tldadmin`
- `tldops`
- `tldtech`
- `use-net`
- `use.net`
- `usenet`
- `usr`
- `uucp`
- `web`
- `web-master`
- `web-masters`
- `web-site`
- `web.master`
- `web.masters`
- `web.site`
- `webmail`
- `webmaster`
- `webmasters`
- `website`
- `who-is`
- `who-is-privacy`
- `who.is`
- `who.is.privacy`
- `whois`
- `whois-privacy`
- `whois.privacy`
- `whoisprivacy`
- `www`

Here's a more generic full list ([JSON format available](https://github.com/forwardemail/reserved-email-addresses-list/blob/master/index.json)) of 1250+ (includes generic, admin, mailer-daemon, and no-reply).

Comment: After approving this as an edit to my post (I thought it was just additions), I see its actually a whole new answer.    That said, its way better then what I wrote, so I'm leaving it.  Cudos to @github-commenter